# angularjs view express doesn't allow `+`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div id="cover_photos_wrap" ng-init="num_cover_photo=[1,2,3,4]">
  <span ng-repeat="photo in num_cover_photo track by $index">
                      <input style="display: none" type="radio" name="cover_photos" id="cover_{{$index+1}}" />
                      <label ng-click="{ selected_cover: $index+1 }" for="cover_{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</label>   
                    </span>
</div>
{{selected_cover}} <!-- nothing? -->
```

I expect I can't get selected_cover but I got an nothing within expression of ng-click.

http://jsfiddle.net/7ehr05ae/

Comment: What should happen on clicking the label? *"I can get selected_cover"* is not explaining that!

Comment: Did you find an answer @maria-jane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I woud suggest creating a function in the controller...

**YOUR CONTROLLER**

```
var app = angular.module('starter', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.changeSelectedCover = function changeSelectedCover(selectedIndex){
     $scope.selected_cover = selectedIndex + 1;
   }
});
```

**RECOMMENDED HTML (STAND ALONE)**

```
<div ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl" id="cover_photos_wrap" ng-init="num_cover_photo=[1,2,3,4]">
    <span ng-repeat="photo in num_cover_photo track by $index" >
      <input style="display: none" type="radio" name="cover_photos" id="cover_{{$index+1}}" />
      <label  for="cover_{{$index+1}}" ng-click="changeSelectedCover($index)">{{$index+1}}</label>   
    </span>
    {{selected_cover}} <!-- nothing? -->
  </div>
```

**IF YOU WANT TO STICK YOUR WAY (NO CONTROLLER)**

```
<div ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl as AppCtrl " id="cover_photos_wrap" ng-init="num_cover_photo=[1,2,3,4]">
        <span ng-repeat="photo in num_cover_photo track by $index" >
          <input style="display: none" type="radio" name="cover_photos" id="cover_{{$index+1}}" />
          <label  for="cover_{{$index+1}}" ng-click="AppCtrl.selected_cover = $index + 1">{{$index+1}}</label>   
        </span>
        {{AppCtrl.selected_cover}} <!-- nothing? -->
      </div>
```

Comment: why use controller as?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for ng-click is wrong, use:

`ng-click="selected_cover = $index + 1"`

However, you might get into problems, because you are not using an object (see angular scope shadowing https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2647-shadowing-isolate-scope-behaviors-in-angularjs.htm).

I'd recommend using the controllerAs syntax, so you'd do something like 
`ctrl.selected_cover = $index + 1` instead of using a variable that might set it on a scope you didn't mean.

Comment: @MariaJane I think we need to see more of your code, but I have included a stand alone example below.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for ng-click was wrong. You'll also noticed I used controllerAs syntax otherwise you'll run into scoping issues. I recommend using this syntax as best practice.

```
<div ng-app="starter">
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
  <div id="cover_photos_wrap" ng-init="num_cover_photo=[1,2,3,4]">
  <span ng-repeat="photo in num_cover_photo track by $index">
     <input style="display: none" type="radio" name="cover_photos" id="cover_{{$index+1}}" />
     <label ng-click="app.selected_cover = $index + 1">{{$index+1}} </label>   
  </span>
    </div>
       {{app.selected_cover}} <!-- nothing? -->
    </div>
</div>
```